# Google Calendar - Small Icons Next To Events

Tags: php, javascript, css, google-calendar-api

I'm working on a website where I would like to embed Google Calendar. I would like to be able to add a small icon next to certain events. I can use the "categories" section of Google Calendar to add a highlight color to the events, but in addition to that, I'd like to specify that some events have food by putting a small fork-and-knife icon next to them.

The only material I could find online about something like this is Google's [Event Flair Lab](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/calendar/EjEJRcnDP1E%5B1-25-false%5D), which not only didn't work for me, but from research appears to have been abandoned. Perhaps there is a way to program this myself?

I'm open to suggestions about other free calendar systems that make this possible other than Google Calendar. Please let me know if you need any other information - this seems like a fairly simple project, but I can't find any information on how to accomplish it.

Comment: you need to write your own i dont see how you could mod an embedded google calendar to your needs

Comment: Write my own calendar entirely? That seems like quite a more daunting task than what I'm up for...

Comment: well mod an existing one, i don't know what yo need ore how your going to use it, but there are many calendar scripts available

Comment: Any suggestions? Maybe a script that can interface with existing Google Calendars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Google calendar supports something like this here:  https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/gadgets/event/.

But if you are open to other widgets, Fullcalendar, http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/, is very robust and quick to implement.  There are some threads documenting exactly the kind of functionality you're after using Fullcalendar, [How to add image to specific events, jquery full calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11961709/how-to-add-image-to-specific-events-jquery-full-calendar).

I would consider using Fullcalendar and an icon-font for your specific need.  You will find a nice shareware fork and knife glyph here http://icomoon.io/app/ by searching "fork".  This is advantageous so that you can switch views (month, week, day) and have optimal control of your icon size and color, among other reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the event flairs working using the guide here [Event Flairs](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/22731/dress-up-your-google-calendar-with-event-flairs/) It looks like google still have this in labs and it might meet your needs

Comment: I mention that specifically in my post, where I say that it doesn't work (and is no longer supported by Google)

Answer (score 0):

First you go to settings, then you choose "labs". Scroll down until you see icons and choose enable. then save and you will see icons :) in order to turn Icons off, do the same thing as above, and choose Disable instead. Now you know how to get Icons! ;)

Comment: I mention that specifically in my post, where I say that it doesn't work (and is no longer supported by Google)